# Unique constraint on combination of two columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to have a unique constraint for a combination of two columns.

Specifically I have two columns A and B.

I have a row like below

```
A     B
1     2
```

Then I want the following combinations to fail when inserted

```
A     B
1     2
2     1
```

I have tried adding a simple constraint

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD CONSTRAINT test_constraint UNIQUE (a, b);
```

but this lets me insert `(2, 1)` when `(1, 2)` already exists.

Is this possible to do? Or will I have to check if the combination exists before I insert?

Comment: In your example you want `(2,1)` fail because already exists `(1,2)` ??

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using an index on expressions:

```
create unique index unq_test_a_b on (test(least(a, b), greatest(a, b));
```

I don't think the `unique` constraint allows expressions (and don't have a convenient Postgres to test on right now), but this is essentially the same thing.