# Unique constraint on all combinations of columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I would like to only have unique combinations of strings:

```
colA     colB
----     ----
bob      tom
ann      bob
tom      tom
```

How do I constrain this table so that `(tom, bob)` cannot be inserted? This would be a non-unique combination because of the existence of `(bob, tom)` in the first record.

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35613450/unique-constraint-on-combination-of-two-columns), but I believe that question focuses on handling this when the data are integers.

Comment: Add unique constraint on multiple columns will do that. Use below query to alter table and constraint to it :

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
  ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint_Name UNIQUE (colA, colB)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have a `unique index` vs a `unique constraint`.  I've found that on columns that require combined uniqueness I probably need an index anyways.  2 birds with 1 stone.

So for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
    [colA] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [colB] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

You could have:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UIDX] ON [dbo].[mytable]
(
    [colA] ASC,
    [colB] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This will prevent an insert of `(tom, bob)` twice.  The given example has `tom` twice in the right column already so I'm assuming row 3 is legal thus my answer, so *if* I'm understanding the question this should work.

Comment: The existence of the first row, `(bob, tom)`, should prevent the insertion of `(tom, bob)` since this is a non-unique combination. I've updated my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with either a TRIGGER or a CHECK CONSTRAINT.

Either way you would check the logic and make sure no row already exists where

```
(NewA = OldA AND NewB=OldB)
OR
(NewA = OldB AND NewB=OldA)
```